# Question about position of charges

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I would like to have this compound but I want the `\oplus` on the left of the oxygen and also the bond is directly bond to the oxygen. I would like to use `\chemleft`, but it come out with many errors. Could you please teach me how to use `\chemleft`?

this is the one that `\oplus` on the right

```
\chemfig{-C(-[:90]H)(-[:270])-C(-[:270])(-)(-[:90]{\oplus}OH(-[:90]H))}
```

this is what I want to do

```
\chemfig{-C(-[:90]H)(-[:270])-C(-[:270])(-)(-[:90]OH\chemleft\oplus(-[:90]H))}
```

Comment: You have several questions that have good answers. However, you did not accept a single answer yet. I assume that you are not aware of the normal process on this site. Please accept the answer that solved your problem best and upvote answers that were helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how `\chemleft` works. Is this wthat you want?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
    
    \title{mechanism}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \newpage
    
    \section*{addition of hydrogen halide to alkene}
    
    \begin{center}
        
    \schemestart    
    \chemfig{-C(-[:90]H)(-[:270])-C(-[:270])(-)(-[:90]{\charge{125:3pt=$\scriptstyle\oplus$}O}H(-[:90]H))}
    \schemestop 
        
    \end{center}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is very similar to what I mean. Thanks a lot. I can modify it myself.

Comment: I would also like to ask how \chemleft work? As I saw others using \chemabove for the charge so I thought both are the same.

Comment: see page 55 of the chemfig [manual](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

you can place any symbol in any direction and distance you want using "invisible" bonds.

```
\schemestart    
\chemfig{-C(-[:90]H)(-[:270])-C(-[:270])(-)(-[:90]OH(-[:130,.25,,,,draw=none]\scriptstyle\oplus)(-[:90]H))}
\schemestop
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Starting from 2021, `chemfig` uses the `\charge` macro which has the following structure : `\charge{‹decoration›}{‹atom›}`; `decoration` allows the placement of electron pairs, charges, partial charges, etc. using `TikZ` syntax.
As an example, the following code (colored in order to show the corresponding angles):

```
\chemfig{-C(-[:90]H)(-[:270])-C(-[:270])(-)(-[:90]\charge{%
    135:3pt=\color{red}{$\scriptstyle\oplus$},%  red \oplus, 135° angle
    45:3pt=\color{cyan}{$\scriptstyle\oplus$}%   blue \oplus, 45° angle
}{O}H(-[:90]H))}
```

yields this figure :

[image: colorful use of \charge]

I think this is the most versatile way to add stuff to a `chemfig` atom, as you can easily specify the angle and distance (by default, `\charge` uses polar coordinates) of your decoration. For more info, the `\charge` paragraph lies at page 33 (section 8) in `chemfig`'s [manual](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/generic/chemfig/chemfig-en.pdf)...